# Assistance with Oauth2 authentication to use with DropBox

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, dropbox

I am building a Windows c# app that needs to upload files to DropBox. Basically I have everything I need for my app(app secret and app key), but I need to have the client tokens saved to my sql DB for future use. According to Dropbox I am unable to save user login info which is good, but finding a good lib is getting tough.I have tried many different DropBox based libraries but run across the following issues:

SharpBox: seems easy enough to use, but need some kind of deserializer to save the client key and client secret anywhere.

OAuth2 Authorizer: Not enough documentation that I can find, in order for me to actually implement this.

DropNet: This is one that looked promising. It's async and looked good, but again I can't find an example of how to perform the auth function and save the variables to a file/DB/Reg/ or anything.

DropBox.API: This is the method that I currently use and it's working. Problem is it's not Async and requires .NET 4.5. I was ok with all the downs but lately found that's it's very touchy about different versions of JSON and other libraries.

I was hoping someone could give me some assistance in getting any of the above OAUTH libs actually working, Just to get the 3 legged auth process working.

UPDATE::

ok so i am going to include some of the code that I am using at the moment, that uses dropbox.api:

```
// Get Oauth Token
    private static OAuthToken GetAccessToken()
    {
        string consumerKey = "mykey";
        string consumerSecret = "myseceret";
        var oauth = new OAuth();
        var requestToken = oauth.GetRequestToken(new Uri(DropboxRestApi.BaseUri), consumerKey, consumerSecret);
        var authorizeUri = oauth.GetAuthorizeUri(new Uri(DropboxRestApi.AuthorizeBaseUri), requestToken);
        Process.Start(authorizeUri.AbsoluteUri);
        MessageBox.Show("Once Registration is completed Click OK", "Confirmation");
        return oauth.GetAccessToken(new Uri(DropboxRestApi.BaseUri), consumerKey, consumerSecret, requestToken);
    }

        // Complete Oauth function and write to file
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show("Please register for dropbox before continuing with authentication. The authorization process will take 1 minute to complete. During that time the backup utility window will be unresponsive. Click yes if you are ready to begin the authorization. HAVE YOU REGISTERED FOR DROPBOX YET?", "DO YOU HAVE A DROPBOX ACCOUNT?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (result1 == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            try
            {
                u_w.Enabled = false;
                var accesstoken = GetAccessToken();
                StringBuilder newFile = new StringBuilder();
                string temptoken = "";
                string tempsecret = "";
                string tempprovider = "";
                string tempstatus = "";
                string[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\cfg\andro_backup.ini");
                foreach (string line in file)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("dbkey:"))
                    {
                        temptoken = line.Replace("dbkey:", "dbkey:" + accesstoken.Token);
                        newFile.Append(temptoken + "\r\n");
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (line.Contains("dbsecret:"))
                    {
                        tempsecret = line.Replace("dbsecret:", "dbsecret:" + accesstoken.Secret);
                        newFile.Append(tempsecret + "\r\n");
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (line.Contains("Provider:"))
                    {
                        tempprovider = line.Replace("Provider:", "Provider:DropBox");
                        newFile.Append(tempprovider + "\r\n");
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (line.Contains("Status:"))
                    {
                        tempstatus = line.Replace("Status:", "Status:Connected");
                        newFile.Append(tempstatus + "\r\n");
                        continue;
                    }
                    newFile.Append(line + "\r\n");
                }
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\cfg\andro_backup.ini", newFile.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("Completed Backup Provider Setup", "Provider Setup Complete");
                Configuration.Reload();
```

The Above works at the moment and I can upload, download files. The issue is it's not Async and I would like to attempt to stay within the .NET 4.0 if possible, this code requires 4.5

Trying to do the same thing with dropnet, I am unable to get it to work at all even using the examples he has given on the page located here https://github.com/dkarzon/DropNet.
I attempted to look at the demos he has on there as well , but they explaing having the user login everytime to perform any functions, where I need the app to be authorized so it can do it's deeds when it needs to. As far as the code I am using for drop net, I literally just copied and pasted what he had there, just to even see if I can get it to connect and still no go.

Comment: Could you post your code so far using DropNet? It looks like it's pretty straightforward to use a saved access token, but it's hard to say what you're missing without seeing what you've tried.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using DropNet similar to the examples all you need to do is save the return object from the `GetAccessToken` method. That returns an instance of a UserLogin object which has the Token and secret on it. Or if you are using the async methods for it then the callback parameter.

Checkout the sample here:
https://github.com/dkarzon/DropNet/blob/master/DropNet.Samples/DropNet.Samples.WP7/MainPage.xaml.cs#L69

Post the code you are using for it so I can give you a better explanation for it.

Comment: actually that helped, I took a second look at the documents and finally pieced things together. Thank You.